# Make drop down lists according to the limit given by user for it

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

Here are my both pages screenshot.

[image]

I want to make a drop down list in my create team page according to the given team limit in teacher home page.
My drop down list is just a sample for explaining this.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use number which you write to team limit as input for "while loop" and reapeat list items until cycle finish.

Team limit will be posted via form from home page to team page as `team_limit`.

```
while($x <= team_limit) {
  echo "<ul>";
  echo "<li>example<li>";
  echo "</ul>";
  $x++;
}
```